# Scroll/Click Function - Processing 2 - Java

Tags: java, twitter, scroll, processing

I am trying to add a scroll function to my code as currently it merely displays the first couple tweets, enough to fill the canvas but no more. How do I go about adding a scroll/click function so the canvas lists other tweets as well?

This is what I have so far with my Twitter API tokens omitted.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Arrays;

ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();

void setup() {
  //Set the size of the stage, and the background to black.
  size(750, 750);
  background(0);

  //Credentials
  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("x");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("x");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("x");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("x");
  TwitterFactory twitterFactory;

  twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
  Twitter twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();

  Query query = new Query("StackOverFow");  
  query.count(100);

  try {
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
    ArrayList tweets = (ArrayList) result.getTweets();

    for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size (); i++) {
      Status t = (Status) tweets.get(i);
      User u=(User) t.getUser();
      String user=u.getName();
      String msg = t.getText();
      Date d = t.getCreatedAt();

      text("User Name - " + user + " Time - " + d + " Message -  " + msg, 
      20, 15+i*50, width-40, 50);


      println("Tweet by " + user + " at " + d + ": " + msg);
      //Break the tweet into words
      String[] input = msg.split(" ");

      println(input);

      for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
        //Put each word into the words ArrayList
        words.add(input[j]);
      }
    };
  }
  catch (TwitterException te) {
    println("Couldn't connect: " + te);
  };
}

int j=0;

void mousePressed() { 
  saveData();
} 

void saveData() { 
  String[] data = new String[words.size()];
  words.toArray(data);
  saveStrings("data/data.txt", data);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Be mindful about asking others to look at your code, though - if you look at your question, you'll see there are code formatting oddities that you can very easily fix by, in Processing, hitting ctrl-T or cmd-T to autoformat the code, so that you can paste that into your question in the knowledge the formatting will be good enough for people to be able to easily read your code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you Mike, I'll make sure to do that now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a handler for `mousePressed`, adding click and scroll handling is the same concept: add [`mouseClicked`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseClicked_.html) for full click handling, and [`mouseWheel()`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseWheel_.html) for handling scroll events.